# SQL SERVER Query Formation on matchin field data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. I need a certain output.

```
Table1
======================
| PropertyID | Name  |
+------------+-------+
| 1          | Pants |
+------------+-------+
| 2          | Dress |
+------------+-------+

Table2
===============
| Description |
+-------------+
| 2-Pants     |
+-------------+
| 1-Dress     |
+-------------+
| Dress       |
+-------------+

Output
==============
| PropertyID |
+------------+
| 1          |
+------------+
| 2          |
+------------+
| 2          |
+------------+
```

Now I need the `ProperyID` where `Name` matches the `Description` field of `Table2`. It does not have to be an exact match. Like "Pant" should match with "2-Pant". I am not able to form a proper query for it. Help please?

Comment: Read about SOUNDEX function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx

Comment: Thnx for the editing Gordon :) Does look so much more btr! :)

Comment: Mxix soundex only works mainly on vowels. I dont need alike sounding fields. Something like
Select PropertyID
from Table1
where Name like/in
(Select Description from Table2)
Something like dis?

Something tat would work like
Name like %<description>%
where <description> is the value of the description field of table2.

I dont want to end up writing a cursor or sumthin. Is der ne other way whr a direct query wud work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `RIGHT JOIN` Table1 to Table2 and use the `LIKE` condition appending the `%` wildcard on two sides of the value from Table1. Use the following query:

```
SELECT T1.PropertyId FROM Table1 AS T1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T2.Description LIKE '%'+T1.Name+'%';
```

[SQLFiddle demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29ca5/3)

[Extra SQLFiddle demo, so you know that the right column is being matched.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29ca5/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f933/1)

```
select t1.PropertyID from  Table2 t2 left join Table1 t1 on t2.Description 
like '%'+t1.name+'%'
```